# Ember Component Is Losing Attribute Binding

Tags: ember.js

I have one Ember.Component created and this is the HTML:

```
<div class="progress-bar-component">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" {{bind-attr style="progressWidthStyle"}} max="100"></div>
</div>
<p class="progress-message">{{message}}</p>
```

I'm rendering it on different templates and when I change the progressWidthStyle property it's updating on the last component instance created. The expected behavior is that when I change the progressWidthStyle, it updates on every component rendered in the app.

Here's the component code

```
import ExposerMixin from 'velocity/mixins/views/exposer';

export
default Ember.Component.extend(ExposerMixin, Ember.Evented, {
  message: 'Content being updated, please do not go offline',
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('progress', 0);
  },
  defaultClass: '.header-progress-bar-holder',
  /**
    Object used to expose these methods globally (see reference to @mixins/exposer.js)
  **/
  config: {
    progress: ['showProgress', 'hideProgress', 'setMessage']
  },
  /**
    Used to render the progress modal on screen.
    @method showProgress
    @params {Integer} fileSize - Total file size
    @params {Integer} actualProgress - The actual progress that the file has
    @public
  **/
  showProgress: function(fileSize, actualProgress, fileId) {
    // Get the current progress value.
    var updateProgress = actualProgress * 100 / fileSize,
      promise;

    // If index panel is showed, we hide it.
    this.sendAction('hidePanels');

    this.sendAction('setFileId', fileId);

    // Shows the progress modal component
    this._show();

    // Set current progress on the progress bar
    this.set('progress', updateProgress);
  },
  /**
    Used to render the progress modal on screen.
    @method _show
    @private
  **/
  _show: function() {
    // Show the progress bar component.
    $(this.get('defaultClass')).addClass('element-visible')
      .removeClass('visually-hidden');
  },
  /**
    Used to set a new message on the progress modal on screen.
    @method setMessage
    @params {String} newMessage - New message to be displayed on the bottom of the progress bar component.
    @public
  **/
  setMessage: function(newMessage) {
    this.set('message', newMessage);
  },
  /**
    Used to hide the progress modal component
    @method _hide
    @private
  **/
  _hide: function() {
    // Hide progress bar component.
    $(this.get('defaultClass')).toggleClass('visually-hidden');
  },
  /**
    Used to hide the progress modal.
    @method hideProgress
    @public
    @returns - Ember.RSVP.Promise instance.
  **/
  hideProgress: function() {
    var self = this,
      promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        // We finished the progress flow and resolves the promise
        resolve();
      }).then(function() {
        // After hide it, reset the progress.
        self._resetProgress();
      });
    // Finally hide the progress bar component.
    this._hide();

    return promise;
  },
  /**
    Used to hide the progress modal.
    @method _resetProgress
    @private
  **/
  _resetProgress: function() {
    this.set('progress', 0);
  },
  /**
    Used to bind to the template with the right style to display current progress.
    @property progressWidthStyle
  **/
  progressWidthStyle: function() {
    return 'width:' + this.get('progress') + '%';
  }.property('progress')
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: will you add the exposermixin as well?

Comment: n/m, I read that wrong, you want one of your components to go affect all of the other components?  So if one of them says hide, hide them all?

Comment: The exposer mixin is one mixin that I use to call the components by console (from another App, nothing to important here). I'm calling the showProgress(100, 30, 1) method from ember-console and I get updated (style="width:30%") the last rendered component (so, if I have 3 components rendered, i am seeing just one component with style="width:30%" and the other two components with style="width:0") I think that's why when Ember creates a new instance of the component it set 'progress' attribute to zero.

Comment: Well, you have three different instances of the component.  If you wanted to change the progress value of each instance you'd have to get a reference to each instance.  I'm a little confused what you mean by ember-console, are you talking about ember inspector?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's ember-inspector. Am I confused or the behavior of Ember.Component is to have something reusable ? How could I get a reference to each instance of the component ?

Comment: Reusable, not static single instance.  Generally components are self contained and aren't accessed externally (beside when you create the instance and pass in the necessary properties)